# using List() with array PHP, Why won't this work?

Tags: php, html, forms, list, function

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `uid`,`name` FROM `location`");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    list($location_id, $location_name) = $result;
?>
<option value="contactLocation.php?view_id=<?php echo $location_id; ?>"><?php echo $location_name; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Can someone help me and tell me why this isn't working? I'm trying to put the uid and name columns into those two variables in the list.

Comment: *sigh* Do you really need to be asked what "isn't working" is supposed to mean?

Comment: usually I just do $result['uid'] and $result['name'] but i want to put this all in one array to seperate variables. I seen this method used before but not exactly sure if this is right. It looks correct. $result is an array. edit: The variables are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re fetching an associative array. You can use [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) or [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) instead for `list()` assignment.

Better yet, upgrade to PDO! (Or MySQLi!)

Comment: Thanks, it seems mysql_fetch_assoc doesn't work with list() for php for some reason. Cheers thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @TheCryptKeeper: Yep, see [the notes section in the docs](http://php.net/list); it only works with numeric arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign it right from the fetch:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `uid`,`name` FROM `location`");
while(list($location_id, $location_name) = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
   <option value="contactLocation.php?view_id=<?php echo $location_id; ?>"><?php echo  $location_name; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```